# Facebook does not display image from the opentag image

Tags: facebook, image, get, facebook-opengraph

I have been trying it for few days and I do not understand what is the issue.
I have setup the Meta Tag opengraph on my website (picture gallery).

Here is an example: http://photos.franck-royer.fr/?f=Photos%2F2011-11-15_Amiga_and_IceCube%2FIMG_6218.JPG

If you look at the source code you can see in the head:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://photos.franck-royer.fr/?f=Photos%2F2011-11-15_Amiga_and_IceCube%2FIMG_6218.JPG"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="Photos/2011-11-15_Amiga_and_IceCube/IMG_6218.JPG"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://photos.franck-royer.fr/?t=Big&f=Photos%2F2011-11-15_Amiga_and_IceCube%2FIMG_6218.JPG"/>
```

If you open the link of og:image you will see that an image is indeed available.

However when scrabing this link with facebook linter:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fphotos.franck-royer.fr%2F%3Ff%3DPhotos%252F2011-11-15_Amiga_and_IceCube%252FIMG_6218.JPG

The scraped information is correct except for the image tag: no image is displayed in the thumbnail.

I do not know if it is related but you can also see at the bottom of the page:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://photos.franck-royer.fr/?t=Big&amp;f=Photos%2F2011-11-15_Amiga_and_IceCube%2FIMG_6218.JPG" />
```

the '&' has been replaced by '&' and thus I am not sure facebook try to get the image by passing the correct get arguments...

Any idea how to fix this?

Many thanks,
Franck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You should use SMALLER image here.

If your image is very large, the facebook will lost time out when try to reach the image
=> So, it will be similar to the image is not found.

And, this image just use to share and send in FB plugin it should be more smaller as possible as.
=> So you can create a thumb picture using for meta tag.

> Sometimes, FB will not show your image.

I think that, maybe before the FB does sync your image or info in mata tag. Wait for several minutes it will be ok.

Comment: Awesome, indeed I need to pass the thumbnail of my image in the og:image tag. Problem solved thanks a lot.